# Spring reference JDBC flaw?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I was just reading the Reference of `Spring Data JDBC` and was wondering if there is an Flaw in it.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/core.support.html
Here is the example code:

```
private static class CustomerMapper implements RowMapper<Customer> {

  public Customer mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    Customer c = new Customer();
    c.setId(rs.getInt("customer.id"));
    c.setName(rs.getString("customer.name"));
    return c;
  }
}
```

And the method gets passed two arguments (`ResultSet rs`, `int rowNum`) while the `rowNum` is not used at all. Is there any other use for the `rowNum` that is not seen in the code?

thanks and greetings,

Whit3hat

Comment: it might be useful to know which row from the sql result you're currently processing. if it's not used in the example it doesn't mean it's flawed :)

Answer (score 1):

mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) method is part of the RowMapper interface.

As far as I can tell (by quickly skimming over Spring Framework's sources) it is not used by any implementing classes for purposes other than logging. I suppose it is present in the method signature to give more options to developers writing classes that implement RowMapper interface.